# Limit textField entry to numerical entries of set length

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm trying to limit 3 different textfields so that you can only enter numbers into them, and so that the number of digits you can enter is limited.

Here's my code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Darwin

class View3on3 : UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var APTeams: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var APRounds: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var APBreakers: UITextField!


override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    initializeTextFields()
}


func initializeTextFields()
{
    APTeams.delegate = self
    APTeams.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad

    APRounds.delegate = self
    APRounds.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad

    APBreakers.delegate = self
    APBreakers.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
{
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}


@IBAction func userTappedBackground(sender: AnyObject)
{
    view.endEditing(true)
}

func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
{
    if string.characters.count == 0 {
        return true
    }

    let prospectiveText = (textField.text as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: String())

    switch textField {
    case APTeams:
        return prospectiveText.containsOnlyCharactersIn("0123456789") && count(prospectiveText) <= 3

    case APRounds:
        return prospectiveText.containsOnlyCharactersIn("0123456789") && count(prospectiveText) <= 1

    case APBreakers:
        return prospectiveText.containsOnlyCharactersIn("0123456789") && count(prospectiveText) <= 3

    default:
        return true
    }

}

}
```

It throws an error at this line:

```
let prospectiveText = (textField.text as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: String())
```

Saying that
'String?' is not convertible to NSString

I followed the tutorial at this site: 
http://www.globalnerdy.com/2015/04/27/how-to-program-an-ios-text-field-that-takes-only-numeric-input-or-specific-characters-with-a-maximum-length/

What am I doing wrong?

PS. The code to call a NumberPad is working fine. When I remove the code to limit the number of digits, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

> Try this swift 2. textField.text is an optional value,so you need to unwrap it before using...That is why you get Stirng? cannot be converted to NSString.

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    if let textFieldText = textField.text {

        let textAfterUpdate = textFieldText as NSString

        print(textAfterUpdate)

    }


 return true

}
```

Comment: Nope, same problem. :/

Comment: which version of swift are you using?

Comment: Yup, still showing same error. I'm using Xcode 7.0 beta 3, Swift 2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83928/discussion-between-thevesh-theva-and-aditya-koukuntla).

Answer (score 1):

Or you could give this a shot, make a method and call it in view did load:

```
func initializeTextFields({
digitsOnlyTextField.delegate = self
digitsOnlyTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.ASCIICapable
```

Then, you can hard code your text field as so:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String)
-> Bool {

case digitsOnlyTextField:
return prospectiveText.containsOnlyCharactersIn("012346789")
```

Give this a shot and shoot me some feedback, good luck!

Comment: Didn't work man. 'case' label can only appear inside a switch statement. Also, prospectiveText is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of the tutorial that you referred to. I wrote it for Swift 1, and the code breaks under Swift 2. Here's the fix:

```
let currentText = textField.text ?? ""
let prospectiveText = (currentText as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I have made some changes in your code..

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let invalidCharSet : NSCharacterSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "0123456789").invertedSet

    let filteredString : NSString = ((string.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(invalidCharSet)) as NSArray).componentsJoinedByString("")

    var allow : Bool = false

    if (string == filteredString) {

        allow = true
    }

    let newLength = count(textField.text) + count(string) - range.length

    switch textField {

    case APTeams:

        if (newLength > 3) {

            allow = false
        }

        return allow

    case APRounds:

        if (newLength > 1) {

            allow = false
        }

        return allow

    case APBreakers:

        if (newLength > 3) {

            allow = false
        }

        return allow

    default:
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked @AshishP in the sense that it didn't throw an error. However, in the Xcode simulator, it still allowed inputs of more than the specified number of characters. Does that mean it failed, or that the simulator doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast the optional to `NSString`. Since you are using swift 2.0 you can guard the value like this:

```
guard let text = textField.text else { return false }
let prospectiveText = (text as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)
```